# How can I shift a low logic voltage to a higher one in the simplest way?

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting

Suppose I want to enable an IC by pulling EN pin high with an Arduino. Suppose that the IC works on 12V and accepts a minimum 8V as high but the Arduino only outputs 3.3V.

What is the simplest way to shift that voltage level? I've seen some level shifter ICs but can't I do it with simpler components? I thought of using two N-MOSFETs as below but still it looks messy.

[image]

I was about to get in trouble for that because the IC I'm working on indeed works on 12V but when I checked the datasheet I learned that it accepts a minimum 2V as high on the EN pin. I'm relieved as I don't need to shift Arduino voltage. Nevertheless, I wanted to ask the question for future use.

Over a request, I've added my incomplete circuit schematic below, the values are wrong. The question is a general level shifting question, it is not about programming an Arduino (the source of input logic could be something else) or gate drivers.

[image]

Comment: How low does it need to go to disable?

Comment: EN pin must go below 0.8V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?  Use a logic level NFET so that the gate gets turned on reasonably with 3.3V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwhvw3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Woow that's some clever thinking. I see, increasing source voltage turns off the MOSFET. This would work even without R1, am I right?

Comment: yeah, you could remove R1 for your application.  This circuit is actually a bi-directional level translator, but removing R1 will make it work in one direction only.

Comment: I couldn't understand how it works to the other direction I will think about it later because it is bedtime. Still I am amazed that this configuration solves level increasing problem with only two components. Thank you.

Comment: The underappreciated common gate configuration.

Comment: One disadvantage. If I/O powers up high-z, then EN is high until software can set it low.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when I/O turns low, 12V shows up at the I/O  pin. What happens if 12V is above max absolute rating for I/O pins?

Comment: @Fredled if R2 wasn't there you'd be correct.  But when I/O goes low, then the 10kΩ will drop ~12V across it.

Comment: R2 will have an 8.7 V voltage drop across it only if there is greater than 0.9 mA through it.  That means the I/O output has to **sink** that current when in the high state, something most outputs can't do.

Comment: @AnalogKid most Arduino are atmega chips which can sink/source over 1mA. But if not, he can always up the resistance to 100k. It's an enable pin not serial port.

Comment: @AnalogKid Also, unless I misread the OP, the voltage needs to go above 8.7V, that's easy when the I/O is at 3.3V.  Then at 900uA i/O will pull it down to 3V as drawn.  100kΩ would pull down more.

Comment: My point is that if the I/O pin cannot sink current when in a high output state, the full 12 V will appear across it.  If the input circuit is connected while the pin is in an output mode (as is often the case), it can be damaged.

Comment: @AnalogKid During I/O rise time, the MOSFET will still conduct until I/O reaches 1.5 or even 2V, while it won't be able to sink any current (because it's rising). So at every change of level, the I/O pin will be under  stress, for a short time with 12V appearing.

Comment: I think as the I/O pin voltage rises, the MOSFET will start to turn off thus, voltage drop on the MOSFET will follow the rise on the I/O pin. That's why no high voltage will appear on the I/O pin.

Comment: @CaveScientist Yes, that's the theory. In practice, you never know when the MOSFET will start yielding and at which impedance. There might be a margin of error in which the curves are not crossing perfectly on the zero axis.

Comment: @Fredled Can you point to or create an example of this non-ideal behavior.  I've not read about it nor can I produce it in simulation.  I don't want to give out bad circuit advice, so if you have an actual analysis, scope capture etc. I'd love to amend my post.

Comment: @AnalogKid Can you point to or create an example of this non-ideal behavior. I've not read about it nor can I produce it in simulation. I don't want to give out bad circuit advice, so if you have an actual analysis, scope capture etc. I'd love to amend my post.

Answer (score 4):

The Arduino pin is under software control so invert the pin in software. So 0 at the pin is enabled and 1 is disabled. Then you eliminate R33 and Q7 taking the EN output from the drain of Q8.

Comment: True, though the same Arduino pin is connected to a MOSFET gate driver so I normally wouldn't be able to invert the pin as I wish. But the MOSFET driver has inverting version so that can be a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Having a gate driver on that pin may add other options. It would be interesting if it was included in your circuit diagram.

Comment: The thing is, I currently have no problem as I stated in the question. Please consider my question as a general level shifting question. Instead of Arduino, there could be some output that cannot be programmed. Still, I've added the incomplete circuit schematic as you wished.

Comment: @CaveScientist, this is a general answer. If you have a 2nd signal that needs to be driven non-inverted then the cheapest solution is to use a 2nd Arduino pin to drive that signal. Use a pin on the same port if you need to be able to change both at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing extravagant using two N-MOSFETS to replicate the signal at a higher voltage. Double MOSFET ic's are common, small, cheap and convenient for this use.

Please note that high level on input pins often depends on the supply voltage. If it's supplied with 12V it may not see 2V as high level. While it will do if supplied with 5V. Check the data sheet carefully.

Comment: Hello, I've checked the bottom of page 3 in the datasheet, I think there is no supply voltage dependency for high level input. https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005344A.pdf